# Is it possible to make a website with Ruby On Rails that scrapes data from another website and displays it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am teaching myself Ruby on Rails. I would like to make website that whenever someone visits it, will scrape another website and display some data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Just remember one things: Don't crawl data within your controller action. Crawling data might be a long running process. The target website might be slow or down, and it will block your entire website. You should use some cron job or job queue to crawl data, and store in your database. The rails app gets data from database, not from the other website directly.

Answer (score 0):

Totally. You can use Nokogiri to take in the contents of a web page, parse it and then display it on your site. It requires some knowledge of the site you are consuming in the sense of the class/id of the elements.

[Nokogiri gem](http://nokogiri.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should use Nokogiri or regular expressions to extract data what you want and then display it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code example to get you going

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://www.stackoverflow.com'){ |f| puts f.read }
```

This will print to your terminal window the HTML from this site, if you don't do so already, use the utility [irb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) to see it work, finally here is a basic way to strip out much of the HTML if you need to ..

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
open('http://www.stackoverflow.com'){ |f| puts strip_tags(f.read) }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have actually been able to write a ruby program that can get the relevant data each time. I just wanted to make sure i can have this run from a website before I go to all the trouble of learning how the rails framework works.